# Why can't the address of sys_call_table be derived using that of system_wq in System.map?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, system-calls, kernel-module, rootkit

After trying the suggested solution for deriving the KASLR offset shift on [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58523370/kernel-module-crash-when-reading-system-call-table-function-address) on this topic, i realized that the run time address of `system_wq` is different from that in `/boot/System.map-$(uname -r)` whether or not KASLR is enabled (although it does remain the same across different KASLR-disabled boots, which obviously doesn't happen on the opposite case).

The following snippet should calculate the `sys_call_table` address using the run time address of `system_wq` and the System.map addresses of both `system_wq` and `sys_call_table` (assume `sysmap_*` to contain the corresponding System.map addresses). `dmesg` outputs are below the snippet.

```
runtime_sys_call_table = (unsigned long *)
((unsigned long)system_wq - (sysmap_system_wq - sysmap_sys_call_table));

printk("System.map system_wq:             0x%lx\n", sysmap_system_wq);
printk("System.map sys_call_table:        0x%lx\n", sysmap_sys_call_table);
printk("Run time system_wq:               0x%lx\n", (unsigned long)system_wq);
printk("Expected run time sys_call_table: 0x%lx\n", (unsigned long)runtime_sys_call_table);
```

### KASLR enabled

**Boot 1**:

```
[  126.922753] [lkm] lkm_init: System.map system_wq:             0xffffffff821204b8
[  127.230661] [lkm] lkm_init: System.map sys_call_table:        0xffffffff81c002a0
[  127.230662] [lkm] lkm_init: Run time system_wq:               0xffff91fcbe40ae00
[  127.230662] [lkm] lkm_init: Expected run time sys_call_table: 0xffff91fcbdeeabe8
```

**Boot 2**:

```
[  140.689652] [lkm] lkm_init: System.map system_wq:             0xffffffff821204b8
[  140.993379] [lkm] lkm_init: System.map sys_call_table:        0xffffffff81c002a0
[  140.993381] [lkm] lkm_init: Run time system_wq:               0xffff9a69be40ae00
[  140.993382] [lkm] lkm_init: Expected run time sys_call_table: 0xffff9a69bdeeabe8
```

### KASLR disabled

**Boot 1**:

```
[  143.699539] [lkm] lkm_init: System.map system_wq:             0xffffffff821204b8
[  144.002094] [lkm] lkm_init: System.map sys_call_table:        0xffffffff81c002a0
[  144.002095] [lkm] lkm_init: Run time system_wq:               0xffff88803e40ae00
[  144.002096] [lkm] lkm_init: Expected run time sys_call_table: 0xffff88803deeabe8
```

**Boot 2**:

```
[  133.828917] [lkm] lkm_init: System.map system_wq:             0xffffffff821204b8
[  134.132394] [lkm] lkm_init: System.map sys_call_table:        0xffffffff81c002a0
[  134.132395] [lkm] lkm_init: Run time system_wq:               0xffff88803e40ae00
[  134.132395] [lkm] lkm_init: Expected run time sys_call_table: 0xffff88803deeabe8
```

### Questions

**1**. Why does the run time address of `sys_call_table` match that of System.map (which i know because system calls were successfully hooked) when KASLR is disabled while that of `system_wq` does not?

**2**. Why does the snippet fail to calculate the run time address of `sys_call_table` whether or not KASLR is enabled?

**3**. If it is the case that the run time address of `system_wq` will differ from that of System.map anyway, then what other exported symbols can be used to derive `sys_call_table`?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the _address_ of `system_wq`?

Comment: Am i not? In `workqueue.h`, `system_wq` is declared as a `struct workqueue_struct *`, so i believe `(unsigned long)system_wq` casts it's address to `unsigned long` correctly; am i wrong?

Comment: The address of `system_wq` is `&system_wq`. You want `(unsigned long)&system_wq`.

Comment: Thank you, that solved it; i was unknowingly assuming `system_wq` as having the same reference level as `sys_call_table`.

Comment: The difference is that `sys_call_table` has array type, so in most expressions it will decay to a pointer to the first element (`&sys_call_table[0]`), but `system_wq` is a simple (non-array) variable (which happens to have pointer type) so you need to use the `&` operator explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ian Abbott's comment solved my problem and made all questions obsolete. For clarification, my confusion was the fact that `system_wq` is a simple pointer to `struct workqueue_struct`, which made me think it already contained the address i wanted; I then thought I only had to cast it as I did with `sys_call_table`, which is actually an array of pointers, making `(unsigned long)sys_call_table` a correct address for `sys_call_table` whereas `(unsigned long)&system_wq` would be for `system_wq`.